# WPF ListBoxItem does not stretch to the maximum width in wrappanel

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a Listbox that it contains custom control and it could wrap automic.My listbox xaml code like below.I need to three items in each row and stretch to maximum width.It will be wrap to next row if items more than three. I need my custom control stretch on in Horizontal not both all side. How can I do that?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox>
                <ListBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ListBox.Template>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <controls:TransducerItem  Margin="5,10"/>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <controls:TransducerItem  Margin="5,10"/>
                </ListBoxItem>


                <ListBoxItem>
                    <controls:TransducerItem  Margin="5,10"/>
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <controls:TransducerItem Margin="5,10" />
                </ListBoxItem>

                <ListBoxItem>
                    <controls:TransducerItem  Width="200" Margin="5,10" />
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UniformGrid with three columns as `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

---

You might also use your TransducerItem control in the `ItemTemplate` of the ListBox

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <controls:TransducerItem  Margin="5,10"/>  
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and then bind the ListBox's `ItemsSource` property to a collection of data items that hold each TransducerItem's data:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TranducerData}">
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Hi Clemens, thank you for your response,I need my custom control controls:TransducerItem stretch only in Horizontal not both all side.

Comment: Then you may set the VerticalAlignment of the UniformGrid. See my edit.

Comment: Hi Clemens, thank you for your response again, the solution works that each row has three custom control,but the custom control does not stretch, any idea?

Comment: Well, its your control, but it should have set its HorizontalAlignment to `Stretch`.

Comment: Should I write control item like        <ListBoxItem>
                        <controls:TransducerItem Width="215" Margin="5,10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>     But the custom control item still not stretched.

Comment: Set `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the ListBoxItem.

Comment: I wrote code like <ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <controls:TransducerItem Margin="5,10"/>
                    </ListBoxItem> and I set background color to my custom control, but it still not stretched.

Comment: I tried the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" property in the itemscontrol. And it works. Thank you again.